# Getting post id from wp_insert_post_data function?

Tags: posts, filters, id

I'm trying to use the function `get_the_tags()` from outside the 'loop'.
I understand this can be achieved by using the post ID like `get_the_tags($postID)`. Does anyone know how I can get the post ID from inside a `wp_insert_post_data` function?

I've tried using `'guid'` which is [suggested here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data), although I've had no luck. I'm also not sure that's even the post ID. Any help with this will be appriciated. Thanks.

EDIT:
Here's the code I'm working with:

```
function changePost($data, $postarr) {

  $postid = $postarr["ID"];
  $posttags = $postarr['tags_input']; // This doesn't work.

  $content = $data['post_content'];
  $subject = $data['post_title'];
  if($data['post_status'] == 'publish') {
    sendviaemail($content, $subject, $postid, $posttags);
  }

return $data;
}

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','changePost','99',2);
```

As you can see, I want to send the post ID, post tags, content and the subject to another function called `sendviaemail`. Everything is okay, except I don't know how to get the tags from the post.

Comment: are you trying to use the `wp_insert_post_data` filter hook?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. That's what I meant. I'm trying to obtain the post ID from within the hook. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the following, '10' is the priority that `my_func` gets called and '2' is the number of arguments that `my_func` accepts.  **The latter is important**, since the `add_filter` function defines the default as 1, but the `wp_insert_post_data` filter hook sends two arguments. If you don't set this as 2 you won't get the second argument.

```
add_filter("wp_insert_post_data", "my_func", 10, 2);
```

Now make your function...

```
function my_func($data, $postarr){
    //at this point, if it's not a new post, $postarr["ID"] should be set
    //do your stuff...
    return $data;
}
```

EDIT--- based on your added code above

If you don't need to modify the post's `$data` before the post is saved then you're using the wrong hook.

Use the `save_post` action hook instead.  This gets called after the post is saved and all the taxonomies are saved. So you don't have to worry about whether new tags have been added.  It sends two arguments to your function: the ID of the post and the post itself as an object.

```
add_action("save_post", "my_save_post");
function my_save_post($post_id, $post){
    if ("publish" != $post->post_status) return;
    $tags = get_the_tags($post_id); //an array of tag objects
    //call your email func etc...
 }
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. That got the ID. :) Having a slight problem getting "get_the_tags()" working though. Is this okay: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/mDP6UzCCMK

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do -- append the tags to post_content? The tags from the editor form are probably in `$postarr`.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, you're right. I've done it now. Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: I take that back. It's not working. Could you please give an example of how to get them from $postarr? Thanks.

Comment: `var_dump($postarr)` from within the function and see if what you need is there. What is not working?  Maybe you should edit your question -- say what you want to eventually do and show your code.  Cheers

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've edited the question. Your suggestion on how to get the post ID worked, just I can't get the tags from the post. It doesn't seem to be in var_dump($postarr) either. Would there be a way to get the tags using the post ID?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Chris. :) Although, I'm planning to write more code in that hook which will edit the post. So is there no way I can do it from that hook? :( I tried using get_the_tags($postid) but it didn't give me anything.

Comment: So there are 2 things that you want to do -- (1) modify the post data before saving and (2) email the contents of the post, including the tags and so on, after it's saved.  Is that right? If so, you are still better off using `save_post` for the latter, because you can get the post in its saved state and not worry about synching up the unsaved with the saved.

Comment: That exactly right. Although I need to email the contents first, before editing the post. When sending the email with the contents/title/tags/etc it needs to have the real contents of the post and not the changed version of it. Which is why I can't edit the post first. I hope that makes sense. Can you suggest how I would do this?

Comment: Or perhaps can I edit a published post? As that would be possible from save_post, right?

Comment: @ChrisCarson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1008/discussion-between-joey-morani-and-chris-carson)